# SSRS. How can I pass one of multiple parameters to a drill through report?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012, server-side-rendering

I have a three charts in one report (using the same dataset) and I'd like to be able to drill through to the same destination report regardless of which chart I click into. 
The destination report also uses the exact same dataset so I know the parameters will match. The destination report will require three different parameters though. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that’s fairly simple,
As you will have 3 parameters and these parameters will be same for each chart just put a action as go to report and add your parameters on click and then pass 3 parameters to this next report .

Here is sample example which will help you.

https://www.tutorialgateway.org/drill-through-reports-in-ssrs/

Comment: Thank you @AnkUser, but I need to clarify my question. Each of the three charts in the first report will pass a different parameter to the destination report. These parameters will be (launch_month, Submission_month and Approval_month).

Comment: That should not be an issue. For example for 1st chart pass launch_month and other 2 as empty. Now in your another report handle these parameters as those which are null or empty shouldn’t be used for filtering out your data in another report. Same goes for chart 2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: Thank you @AnkUser. So in the first chart I pass launch_month and the other two as nulls within the action.  In the destination report would the query end in something along the lines of WHERE launch_month =@ launch OR submission_month = @ submission OR approval_month= @ approval ?

Comment: In another report there are 2 ways you can handle this. Either do this on ssrs side I.e do not change query rather filter dataset from ssrs expression. 2nd way in your query use where clause as mentioned but you will have to handle inside your query when you pass other 2 parameters as null or empty. I would first try with ssrs expression on dataset rather than query and if this work then will try to optimize with 2nd option.